# How do I do remote POW with iota.js

Tags: pow, powbox

With the recent iota.js update, how would I do remote POW?

If my device is too weak but the server I am connected to has POW enabled.

I have transaction objects.

Answer (score 1):

You simple.add `remote=True` to the connection parameters but that might have been removed since chrysalis. Maybe POW altogether will be removed.

Comment: This was pre chrysalis and might not make any sense anymore